# Chef: Do something when a service is started

Tags: chef-infra

I'm facing up with solving a tipical problem a newbie finds 5 minutes having started with chef.

Concretly:

1. I want a service starts.
2. When it is started do something (execute a command, create a file,...)

Currently, I'm solving that using this:

```
service 'mongod' do
  action :start
end

execute "Add Mongo Users" do
  command "mongo #{host}:#{port} /tmp/mongo.setup.users.js"
  retries 5 #times
  retry_delay 10 #seconds
end
```

It's not an elegant way to make it works I believe.

My question is: Is there any way to solve it using notifications and subscription. I've already took a look on documentation but I don't quite figure out how to get it.

Comment: Is your JS script idempotent? I.e. Will it do the right thing if run twice?

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as:

```
execute 'foo' do
  cmd 'bar'
  subscribes :run, 'service[mongod]', :immediate # or :delayed
end
```

In general, the way `notifies` and `subscribes` is:

```
subscribes|notify, 'resource_type[resource_name]', :timer
```

Also, as @coderanger stated, I would be really careful with that javascript not being idempotent (This mean here, that it creates over and over the users in this case, even if they already exist).

Personally I think it would be more elegant writing [your own library](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) for this, there is a [MongoDB driver for Ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongo/versions/2.2.5) that you can use to Create/Remove/Edit users, indexes, documents... while keeping it all clean and maintained inside your ruby Chef code, being (in my opinion) something more similar to the concept of "infrastructure as code".

Comment: Thanks @Navarro. I've tried your approach, I think I'm doing something quite wrong. I've edited the post. Am I really doing something wrong?

Comment: I've just replaced this post edition by a new post on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365961/chef-mmake-sure-a-service-is-listennig-on-network)