# Chef: mmake sure a service is listennig on network

Tags: chef-infra

I'm using [this `mongodb3 cookbook`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mongodb3) in order to install a mongodb instance.

I'm trying to perform an script when service starts:

```
execute "Add Mongo Users" do
  command "mongo #{host}:#{port} /tmp/mongo.setup.users.js"
  subscribes :run, 'service[mongod]', :delayed
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
==> Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> ---- Begin output of mongo localhost:30158 /tmp/mongo.setup.users.js ----
==> STDOUT: MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
==> connecting to: localhost:30158
==> 2017-06-05T07:39:48.136+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:30158, in(checking soc
ket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
==> 2017-06-05T07:39:48.136+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:30158, co
nnection attempt failed :
```

So, as you can see, service is not running yet when command is performed (I'm getting a network error).

I've took a look on cookbook repository code. According to [this peace of code](https://github.com/sunggun-yu/chef-mongodb3/blob/master/recipes/default.rb#L137), the service is started...

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be that the command is a bit too fast. Triggering a service to start does not mean that it's ready to accept connections.

Comment: Mind the spelling in your subject, please.

Comment: Maybe update the `command` parameter's value and prepend `ss -ntl;` to output the list of listening ports first (to check if I'm right).

Comment: You are right. Service is not listening to network when command is performed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As triggering the start of a service does not mean that it's immediately ready to accept connections, you need to wait for a bit of time.

- A common approach is to add an additional, hardcoded delay, e.g.

  ```rb
  command "sleep 3; mongo.."
  ```

  Downside: 3 seconds might be enough on machine A, but not on machine B. (So put 20sec and you've solved it for 99.9% of the cases - but didn't become a better programmer ;-)).
- A better approach can be e.g. seen in the [*jenkins* cookbook's helper library](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/494e4ae6e8df8b1d73432d75318e56d5417d8ff7/libraries/_helper.rb#L425-L447):

  ```rb
  def wait_until_ready!
    Timeout.timeout(timeout, JenkinsTimeout) do
      begin
        open(endpoint)
      rescue SocketError,
        Errno::ECONNREFUSED,
        Errno::ECONNRESET,
        Errno::ENETUNREACH,
        Timeout::Error,
        OpenURI::HTTPError => e
        # If authentication has been enabled, the server will return an HTTP
        # 403. This is "OK", since it means that the server is actually
        # ready to accept requests.
        return if e.message =~ /^403/

        Chef::Log.debug("Jenkins is not accepting requests - #{e.message}")
        sleep(0.5)
        retry
      end
    end
  rescue JenkinsTimeout
    raise JenkinsNotReady.new(endpoint, timeout)
  end
  ```

  This code repeatedly tries to connect to Jenkins, until it either works or a timeout is reached. You should be able to adapt this to mongo (you could call the command and check if it succeeds, or directly connect to the TCP port as the Jenkins code does.
- A way in between would be to use Chef's `retry` parameter:

  ```rb
  execute "Add Mongo Users" do
    command "mongo #{host}:#{port} /tmp/mongo.setup.users.js"
    retry 10
    subscribes :run, 'service[mongod]', :delayed
  end
  ```

  I'm not entirely sure, if it will work, as the `mongo` command probably returns the failure pretty quickly, leaving little time up to the service to start (so combine with the all-mighty `sleep`?). Further, depending on the command that you execute, make sure that you won't cause negative side-effects (when it can connect to the service, but fails in a later step - and the result of this is that it runs once again. Think of data corruption and friends here).